# Tools to set up unix development environment automatically?

Tags: linux, macos

I really love programming. But the cumbersome part is to setup the unix development environment.

I use ruby on Ubuntu/Mac os x.

I'm aware there are tools like rvm and vagrant that can help you in the process, but even though I have to set up everything manually in the OS.

Are there tools for setting up a full development environment automatically for me so that I can start coding immediately or are you all doing it manually too?

EDIT: This look interesting: http://www.atmos.org/cider/intro.html. Are there more tools like this?

Comment: Define "full unix development environment". One could argue pretty persuasively that emacs (or vim if you're one of *those* people),the  gcc tool chain, and the standard headers is a "full" environment for some purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XCode (to get started on a Mac), compile ruby or get it using RVM and add your editor of choice and you are done. =)

If prefer to use an IDE:

1. [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/features/scripting/index.html)
2. [Eclipse DLTK](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/)
3. [Aptana Studio2](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio2) (for Rails development)